# Python visualization - histograms

Tags: python-3.x, histogram, data-visualization

the following two questions are regarding a histogram I am trying to build.

1) I want the bins to be as follows:
       [0-10,10-20,...,580-590, 590-600].                                                               I tried the following code:

```
 bins_range=[]                                                                                   
 for i in range(0,610,10):
    bins_range.append(i)                                                   
 plt.hist(df['something'], bins=bins_range, rwidth=0.95)
```

I expected to see bins as above with their corresponding amount of samples for each bin, but instead I got only 10 bins (as the default parameter).

2) How can I change the y-axis as follows: say my max bin contains 40 samples, so instead of 40 on the y-axis I want it to be 100%, and the others correspondly. I.e., 30 will be 75%, 20 will be 50% and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be working OK. You can even pass the `range` command directly to the `bins` parameter of `hist`.

To get the y-axis as percentages, I think you need two passes: first calculate the bins to know how much the highest bin contains. Then, do the plotting using `1/highest` as weights. There is a numpy `np.hist` that does all the calculations without plotting.

Use the `PercentFormatter()` to display the axis in percentages. It gets a parameter to tell how many 100% represents. Use `PercentFormatter(max(hist))` to get the highest value as 100%. If you just want the total as 100%, just pass `PercentFormatter(len(x))`, without the need to calculate the histogram twice. As internally the y-axis is still in values, the ticks don't show up at the desired positions. You can use `plt.yticks(np.linspace(0, max(hist), 11))` to have ticks for every 10%.

To get nicer separations between the bars, you can set an explicit edge color. Best without the `rwidth=0.95`

Example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter

x = np.random.rayleigh(200, 50000)
hist, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=range(0, 610, 10))
plt.hist(x, bins=bins, ec='white', fc='darkorange')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(max(hist)))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0, max(hist), 11))

plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: To use matplotlib's standard yticks, and having the y-axis also internally in percentages, you can use the `weights` parameter of `hist`. This can be handy when you want to interactively resize or zoom the plot, or need horizontal lines at specific percentages.

```
plt.hist(x, bins=bins, ec='white', fc='dodgerblue', weights=np.ones_like(x)/max(hist))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))
```